# print with the highest count in python

Tags: python

I want to print only the first 3 of highest count in the dictOfNumberOfDocumentsWithTermInside

I want output to be `('Bahrain', 'museum' , 'royal' )`

```
allvocandcount = []
for index, voc in enumerate(allDocumentsNoDuplicates):
    count = 0
    for x in allDocumentsTokenized:
        if voc in x and voc not in " ":
            count += 1
    allvocandcount = (voc, count)
    print(allvocandcount)
```

output:

```
('Bahrain', 5)
('one', 1)
('museum', 5)
('earliest', 1)
('royal', 4)
('areas', 1)
('convert', 1)
('Islam', 1)
```

Comment: you need to provide the `dictOfNumberOfDocumentsWithTermInside` in order of the community will be able to help; read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DavidS hi, i did some changs in the code, can you check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you could use the `sorted()` function which returns a sorted values of the specified iterable object. Here to get the `iterable` in your case, we could use `values()` of given dictionary. The `get_sortable` is a function to execute to decide the member on which ordering might be performed. In other way, what key does is, it provides a way to specify a function that returns what you would like your items sorted by. In your case, we are instructing through the function that we want to sort based on last member of your tuple instance. Lastly, `reverse`, a bool value to decide the sorting order which is by default ascending (`False`). In your case, we need to return the highest (descending) number and hence it is `True`.

```
def get_sortable(item):
    return item[-1]
x = {   0: ('Bahrain', 5),
        1: ('one', 1), 2: ('museum', 5),
        3: ('earliest', 1),
        4: ('royal', 4),
        5: ('areas', 1),
        6: ('convert', 1),
        7: ('Islam', 1),
        8: ('oldest', 2),
        9: ('', 0)}

x=sorted(x.values() , key = get_sortable, reverse = True)[0:3]

#to print sorted tuple list
print(x)

#to print first values of each tuples (as you requested)
print([t[0] for t in x])
```

[image]

Comment: can i write x = {allvocandcount} , as it might valuse might changes and want printer only Bahrain , museum , royal without the numebrs

Comment: Yes. You could mentioned your dictionary allvocandcount in place of x. x was to demonstrate how we could do this.

Comment: i get this error :     x = sorted(x.values(), key=get_sortable, reverse=True)[0:3]
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @malsaeed, Not sure what you means. Please post complete code. So that I can help further

Comment: instead of x = {   0: ('Bahrain', 5),
        1: ('one', 1), 2: ('museum', 5),
        3: ('earliest', 1),
        4: ('royal', 4),
        5: ('areas', 1),
        6: ('convert', 1),
        7: ('Islam', 1),
        8: ('oldest', 2),
        9: ('', 0)}   want to add x ={allvocandcount} as the values of allvocandcount is changeable

Comment: x was mentioned as an example. Now if you have your dictionary as allvocandcount then you could say x = allvocandcount. Here allvocandcount will be you dictionary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming d is:

```
d = {0: ('Bahrain', 5), 1: ('one', 1), 2: ('museum', 5), 3: ('earliest', 1), 4: ('royal', 4), 5: ('areas', 1), 6: ('convert', 1), 7: ('Islam', 1), 8: ('oldest', 2), 9: ('', 0)}
```

You can use **lambda** expression as 'key' argument to **sorted** function:

```
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda key_d: key_d[1][1], reverse=True)
print([i[1][0] for i in sorted_d[0:3]])
```

So you output will be as expected.

Comment: do i need to add any import !

Comment: No you don't, all needed facilities are already build in Python interpreter

Comment: hi, its work but its giving me the lowest 3 how to get the hightest 3, what i need to change ?